# Why is #include <iostream.h> bad?

Tags: c++, coding-style, code-quality, coding-standards, headers

I was reading [another thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126950/books-about-learning-programming-with-c-as-a-first-language) where a guy asked about C++ books for beginners, and one of the programmers answering wrote this:

> Some warnings: avoid all books that present an "hello world" stating with
>
> ```
> #include <iostream.h>
> ```

I opened my C++ book and sure enough it included the iostream header like the example above.

Why is that bad? What other pointers should I keep in mind when learning C++?

Background: I am proficient with C and I'll start to learn C++ this next semester.

Comment: Another, related pointer, is to include `cstdio`, not `stdio.h` (the latter is deprecated).

Comment: @AntonGolov Opinions differ. Many experts prefer <stdio.h> as there is no **technical reason** why <cstdio> should be prefered.

Comment: @Sjoerd The fact that `<cstdio>` is guaranteed to provide the names in `namespace std` is reason enough for me to prefer it. I know that it might *also* provide them in the global name-space just as `<stdio.h>` *might* provide them in `namespace std`. It is also a matter of consistency if you make it a habit to always use the `<c…>` headers. And for some headers, you'll really want this because they enhance the C interface with additional function overloads, for example.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The header iostream.h is a non-standard header and does not exist on all platforms. As a matter of fact it does not exist on my system (using g++ and the GNU libstdc++). So any code using it would simply not compile on my system.

The `iostream.h` header used to be common before C++ was first standardized in 1998. But since the 98 standard used `<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>`, the latter has fallen out of favor (being non-standard and all) and is no longer supported on all platforms. Code that uses it should be considered non-standard legacy code and is not portable. Books that teach it should be considered outdated and avoided.

Comment: I wouldn't avoid a book outright just because of a trivial preprocessor syntax issue. It could be a great book while a terrible book could be using the modern syntax.

Comment: @Lord Tydus The fact that any given pre-98 book _could_ be a great book does not negate the fact that statistically, you would be better off avoiding pre-98 books.

Comment: @LordTydus: Totally disagree. The style and usage of C++ is not the same as in 98 thus it is not just fixing syntactic issues.

Comment: @LordTydus If the old syntax plain and simply does not compile on modern compilers, you'll have a hard time using a book that teaches the old syntax. Note that any book that teaches the usage of iostream.h almost certainly doesn't teach e.g. namespaces either, so even after replacing iostream.h with iostream, your code won't work. If you have to google or ask for help on SO every time you want to compile an example from the book, that's not a very effective way to learn C++.

Comment: @LordTydus: In general, I've found that books that use headers like that tend also to use bad practices and are riddled with errors. I've taken to collecting such books *just to keep them out of circulation.*

Comment: I've encountered a compiler that implemented `<iostream.h>` as merely an include of `<iostream>` and a `using namespace std;`

Comment: @LordTydus: It's not just about that one header. The fact is, if the header is used in that book, it probably says a lot about the quality of the rest of the book.

Comment: @LokiAstari: So, is there any difference between <iostream> & <iostream.h> ?

Comment: @PravasiMeet: <iostream.h> was deprecated in 1998. You should **NOT** use it.

Comment: @Brian Then you encountered a very friendly compiler.  Ideally, including its `iostream.h` would also emit a custom warning, something like `Warning: Header '<iostream.h>' is a non-standard header that was commonly used before C++ was officially standardised.  Please update your code to use '<iostream>' instead.  Note that with this compiler, '<iostream.h>' includes '<iostream>', and specifies using-directive 'using namespace std;'.`

Answer (score 56):

`#include <iostream.h>` is a sign that the book was written prior to the first C++ standard in 1998 (the standard header is `iostream`).

The problem is that older C++ code tends to be written in ways that are considered bad practice today.  In particular,

- The use of C-style arrays rather than container classes like `std::string` and `std::vector`.
- The use of explicit `close` functions rather than RAII.

`iostream.h` isn't the *worst* thing a pre-1998 book will get wrong, but it's likely to be the *first* thing that a pre-1998 book will get wrong.

Comment: Nailed it with your final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this comes a bit late but for what it's worth, on a unix/linux box do `ls /usr/{local/,}include/c++/*` or similar, according to your layout and paths. You could pipe to `grep` looking for the header in question, like:

```
ls /usr/{local/,}include/c++/* | grep iostream
```

This entails a look-up for `iostream.h` as well as any other superstrings.

Or run `find / -type f -name iostream 2> /dev/null | grep include` or `locate iostream | grep include` (provided the database is current, otherwise prepend with a call to `updatedb`)--these, however, will print also non-system-wide includes, so please adjust appropriately.
The actual C++ include path is easily found with something like:

```
g++ -v 2>&1| sed -rn 's/.+gxx-include[^=]+=([^ ]+).+/\1/p' # adjust iff empty
```

Equivalently on Windows and other machines. I guess the idea is clear--such a file as `iostream.h` doesn't exist in the system include path by default any longer, you still, however, can find legacy libc++ distributions with `iostream.h` either soft-linked to `iostream` or as its copy. So this is not a matter of style but rather of the circumstances. You could ship your own `iostream.h` with your project just make sure it's contained in the include path where your compiler looks up for the `<...>` headers.

Comment: Very practical but doesn't really address the real fundamental point.

Answer (score -1):

Just dropping my 2 cents. I don't think there is a correlation between ".h" and the quality of a book. This is a minor syntax issue. Back in the day it was actually the correct sytnax.

Is it possible to have a great book with iostream.h? yes

Is it possible to have a terrible book with iostream? yes

I would rely on online user reviews (and my own review after reading) to judge the quality of a book.

Comment: Problem is, are you sure you want a book from "back in the day?"

Comment: Is Lisp outdated because it's from 1958? We utilize Pythagoras's work in every modern missile system even though the math is thousands of years old. In the current C++ book market the ".h" books may well be terrible. But it is a quality of book issue, not a ".h" issue. ".h" isn't even programming logic, it's for the preprocessor.

Comment: but will someone learning the language for the first time know when the book is telling them something wrong?  How much time and frustration will they go through before finding out that the ".h" is now incorrect?  And in how many other ways is the book out of date?

Comment: The trouble is the usage of C++ has changed significantly since those books were written. The whole way you think and use C++ is not the same as those books will present as they do not have any of the facilities that modern C++ has. As a result you will be teaching yourself C with classes not C++.

Comment: Modern C++ is nothing from '98.

Comment: @Loki Astari: C++ has really become a very different language wrt to what it used to be 10, 15 years ago. I often think that the language should get a new name to make this difference clear.

Comment: @Giorgio: ++C++

Comment: @Loki Astari: Yes, for example. I had thought of MPL (multi-paradigm language) or something like that. Anyway, C++ is no longer (only) an object-oriented extension of C. I think it would also be time to drop backward compatibility with C since the C and C++ communities have become rather independent from each other: you do not need backward compatibility to encourage C programmers to adopt C++.

Comment: @Giorgio: Boring. What about ACRE. Advanced C on Ritalin with Exceptions. Acre also implies it covers a lot of ground. :-)

Comment: @Loki Astari: :-) You really do not want to drop its relation to C from the name. ;-)

Comment: At least, ACRE sounds a lot better than BJ (Broken Java) ;-)

Comment: @ammoQ I find java more broken in some aspects than C++, for example, the template system of C++ is much better than java, as I can do much more things in it than in java. Also having a multibyte library can be bad sometimes, because it forces you to use the same base library even if you want to do something different or if you not use something, for example AWT and Swing in server applications. But other things, java does right and the ABI is one of them, since all java programs are much more modular than C++ ones. Others are just equal, like multiple inheritance vs interfaces.

Comment: Coyote21: My comment wasn't really serious, I just needed a word that starts with B to get to that abbreviation for you-know-what. Make it "Better Java" if you like.

Comment: This answer is just assertions without arguments, and doesn't address the real issues brought up by others. I think the answer would be better with some discussion of why a book on pre-standard C++ (or, worse, one written by somebody who didn't understand the difference, and just writes what works on his or her favorite compiler) is likely to be as good as a more modern one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "syntax" whatsoever.

Comment: -1. As @LightnessRacesInOrbit points out, this isn't a simple syntactic issue. The change from <xxxx.h> to <xxxx> was done for a very important reason: to maintain backwards compatibility for code that doesn't use namespaces when the facility was introduced and the standard library was moved into the std namespace. You can therefore be confident that a book using <iostream.h> doesn't teach this critical feature of the language, and is therefore so incomplete as to be virtually useless.