# Why isn't iostream included as a header file anymore?

Tags: c++

First of all I have gone through this question [Why is #include <iostream.h> bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127023/why-is-include-iostream-h-bad) and there the reason was simply that it is outdated but I personally think that as a header iostream was better cos you don't have to declare objects like cout and endl in global scope cos they were already in global scope and moreover since # is not used anymore that means it does not comes under a pre-processor directive. I just need to know that why was this done? I still use turbo sometimes and am comfortable in using it in c++ programs even though gcc and g++ provide better debuggers and everything.

Comment: The best point made by jozefg was about the values of std being loaded in the global namespace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the question. It's bad to include `iostream.h` because nowadays you should be using `iostream`. `iostream.h` is out of date, #include-ing it simply means that your code may or may not break, or shoot monkeys out of your nose, it's implementation defined.

Moving to `iostream` is simply moving to the standard version. You get the guarantee of it working, having an exception aware API, better localization, etc, etc.

Also, you **don't** want all of `std` dumped into global namespace. There is tons of stuff in there that you don't want to know about. Typing those 5 extra characters prevents weird errors if you have a class called `map` or something.

That being said, if you really want to use C++ as it was before 1998, have at it. But you're throwing away community support (The C++ community has moved on), updates, and any modern innovations from the last 1.5 decades. I think these outweigh the only downside I see, learning a few new things about how C++ has changed.

Comment: @CAO Anytime, if my answer answers your question you can click the green checkbox to mark it as accepted

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a time constraint on the script of this page.